# How to add another check class to replace the current active class when user clicks to another link like a step by step menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added class `active` via jquery each time when user clicks on nav menus. How do I add another class `check` every time user performs menu clicks?

The behavior of my menus would be like a step by step menus. For example, when user clicks on `test 1` it will set the `li` to active. And when user clicks to `Test 2` it will set it to active and the previous menu will be replaced by the `check` class.

[image]

Like this example image above.

This is my jquery code. Does anyone has any idea how to alter the Jquery code to perform above?

**HTML**

```
<nav id="sidebar" class="get-qoute-sidebar">

    <ul class="menus">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#"><span>Test 1</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"></i><span>Test 2</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span>Test 3</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span>Test 4</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span>Test 5</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span>Test 6</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span>Test 7</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //load the functions
    activeSideBar();
});
function activeSideBar() {
    // set active classes on side bar nav li a
    $("body").on("click", 'nav#sidebar.get-qoute-sidebar ul li a', function (e) {
      $('nav#sidebar.get-qoute-sidebar ul li.active').removeClass('active');
  
      var $parent = $(this).parent();
      $parent.addClass('active');
  
      e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one:

```
function activeSideBar() {
    // set active classes on side bar nav li a
    $("#sidebar .menus li").on("click", function() {
      $(this).siblings(".active").removeClass("active").addClass("check");
      $(this).addClass("active").removeClass("check");

     // Remove class of the next sibling when going a step back
     $(this).next().removeClass("check");
  
     // Remove class of all following siblings when going a few steps back
     $(this).find("~ .check").removeClass("check");

     // When user jumps directly to step5 mark all previous elements as checked
     $(this).prevAll().addClass("check");
    });
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is what I aimed to achieve. but how do you reset also to class `active` and also remove the `check` class to other siblings when user clicks to the previous menu steps? Because when user goes back to previous steps, it will not remove.

Comment: @laurence-keith-albano I have updated my answer. Can you please check if that is what you need?

Comment: yes already implemented this, but just got stuck on 1 problem when user goes back to the previous step > e.g. Click > step 3 > go back to step 2 > the `check` class is still on the step 3 `menu`. It should also remove the class `check` on that step 3 menu. Any Idea how to tweak it a bit?

Comment: I have edited the answer to cover theses scenarios. `$(this).next().removeClass("check");` will remove the class `check` when you go back one step (e.g. from step3 -> step2). I have also included the case if you go back some more steps like from step6 -> step3. In this case I remove all `check` classes from the steps which are after the one selected with the `active` class. If you don't need that, please remove the last line.

Comment: great!! this is the one that I need. Thank you so much!

Comment: last question, what if a user will jump straight to Step 5? How to check all from step 1 - 4 when step `5` is active?

I'm guessing adding this in the code `$(this).prev().addClass("check");` will this be able to solve it?

Comment: I have updated my post to cover this scenario.